# Refresh TOKEN and PKCE extension

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, pkce, oauth-refresh-token, wso2-asgardeo

I am using the asgardeo library for Tomcat and reading the documentation I cannot find how to request a new AccessToken because the previous one has expired and I was wondering if it is possible to use the PKCE extension in the calls

Comment: the property grant_type it is never set by code

Answer (score 0):

I think it hasn't been implemented by default( eg. HTTPSession BasedOID Processor class ). Maybe you have to extend BasedOID Processor with a new method and implement it.